# Why won't this CSS menu work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Please take a look at my code here.  These "drop up" menus work just fine everywhere but IE.  I'm using IE 8 but as far as I know it also doesn't work in earlier versions.  I've been searching around the Interwebs for the last few hours trying to figure this out and it's come to this.  Please help me if you can!  Thank you.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<STYLE>
#footer {
background-image:url(gradientl.gif);
background-position:left;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
text-align:right;
padding:20px;
background-color:#d5cfbf;
}

#nav-wrapper {
padding: 10px;
}

#nav {
letter-spacing:3px;
font-size:16.5px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
background:#d5cfbf;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
float:right;
list-style-type: none;
}

#nav, #nav * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

/* Head links */
#nav li.headlink { float: left; margin-left: -1px; padding: 0 10px; text-align: left; }
#nav li.headlink a { display: block; padding: 2px; text-decoration: none; }

/* Child lists and links */
#nav li.headlink ul {
display: none;
width:140px;
position:absolute;
  margin: -104px 0 0 -5px;
background:#d5cfbf;
border-bottom:none;
text-align: left;       
}

#nav li.headlink ul li a {
color:#fff;
}

#nav li.headlink:hover ul {
display: inline-block;
}

#nav li.headlink ul li a { 
padding: 5px;
height: 17px;
}

/* #nav li.headlink ul li a:hover { } */

#nav li ul li.current a {
color:#fff;
}

/* styling */
#nav a {color:#069; }
#nav ul li a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
#nav li a:hover, #nav li ul li a:hover {color:#069;}
/* #nav li.headlink { } */
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<!--nav bar-->
<div id="footer">
<a href="index.html" title="Home">Put Home Image Here</a>
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <!--START NAV UL-->
        <ul id="nav">
            <!--portfolio-->
                <li class="headlink"><a href="/portfolio">photography</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="darkroom.html">darkroom</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portrait.html">portrait</a></li>
                    <li><a href="digital.html">digital</a></li>
                    <li><a href="shows.html">shows</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                <!--end portfolio-->
                <!--misc begin-->      
                <li class="headlink"><a href="index.html">misc</a>          
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="video.html">video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="programming.html">programming</a></li>
                    <li><a href="audio.html">audio</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <!--misc end--> 
                <li class="headlink"><a href="printweb.html">print &amp; web</a></li>
                <li class="headlink"><a href="bio.html">bio</a></li>
            <li class="headlink"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--END NAV UL-->
    </div>      
</div>
<!--nav bar END-->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/veQXp/  Your document doesn't appear to have a proper doctype, which might be causing issues.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you!  This is a friend's code, and I immediately noticed there was no DOCTYPE but overlooked it as the problem while looking for the bug in the "code."  I was more interested in cleaning up the code and looking for known bugs than starting with the most immediate thing that was missing.  Lesson learned!  Thank you! (BTW, I tested it on Windows XP running IE 8)